# text processing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have this code that looks inside a file and picks up 5000 words one at a time written on a new line. `parsing` is my variable, in this case it equals "economist".  If the words in the "data" file are within `parsing`, then the word is appended to the output list.

The problem is why the words `'on'` and `'no'` are repeatedly appended? This happens with some other phrases and not necessarily with all. The words `'on'` and `'no'` are repeated only once in the data file.

Using set helps with the repeat but some words are repeated in the phrase so I lose them.

My code for reading the file into data:

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("words.txt", 'r')]

output = []
for each in data: 
        if parsing != "" and each in parsing:
            output.append(each)
```

Samples:

```
phrase = economist
sortedout = ['economist', 'on', 'no', 'on', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no']
```

and

```
phrase = timesonline  # with this one 'in' gets repeated and not no
sortedout = ['online', 'online', 'time', 'line', 'line', 'son', 'in', 'on', 'so', 'me', 'in', 'on', 'so', 'in']
```

It is a hacker rank challenge. Here is the 
Data File, which is suppose to be on their local drive and the Challenge.

When I do this `[d for d in data if d == "on" ]` it returns more than one 'on' and it should not.

Comment: The little bit of code you posted looks fine. It will be difficult to investigate further without a [mcve].

Comment: What is in your `data`?  A list with all words in the document? Seens so - and that you have the other words, in that order, in the text.

Comment: For the record, you could simplify the code to: `output = [d for d in data if d in parsing] if parsing else []` to simplify to the filtering list comprehension, and avoid all the work when `parsing` is empty (so your `parsing != ""` test would cause the loop to do nothing anyway). Or to avoid all the verbosity on one line: `output = []` then `if parsing: output.extend(d for d in data if d in parsing)`. By just testing `parsing`, not `parsing != ""` or `parsing != []`, you can switch the type of `parsing` without needing to change the test; empty sequences are falsy, non-empty are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether a string is in another string:

`if parsing != "" and each in parsing:`

...so if `parsing` is equal to `economist`, then your statement evaluates to `True` for `economist`, `no` and `on` because these are substrings of `economist'.

```
>>> 'on' in 'economist'
True
```

if you want to match entire strings, you can check the item against a list of strings

```
>>> 'on' in ['economist']
False
```

So, re-writing your code (using a list with more than one element, for clarity):

```
>>> data = ['economist', 'blah', 'on', 'engineer' ,'no', 'gin' ,'economist']
>>>
>>> parsing = ['economist', 'engineer']
>>> output = []
>>> for each in data:
...         if parsing != [] and each in parsing:
...             output.append(each)
...
>>> print output
['economist', 'engineer', 'economist']
```

Edit:
I agree that the text in the challenge you link to in the comments implies that the words in the list are unique, but they are not. I've just done a very simple manual text search and counted two occurrences of `on` five of `no`, and one of `economist`, just like your results.

**Tip:** If your code isn't generating the expected results from your source data - check your assumptions about the source data are correct :)

Comment: my data =['market','watch'] and parsing = ['marketwatch'] I am trying to make output=['market','watch'] ofcourse data is 5000 words and I am trying to parse jointed words into single words. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Also I understand why it finds 'on' and 'no' but why more than once?

Comment: Can you post a link to the data file? ([Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34613294/edit) it into your question, rather than as a comment here). Also the code that reads the file into `data`

Comment: it is a hacker rank challenge data file https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/479/assets/words.txt, which is suppose to be on their local drive and the challenge is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/url-hashtag-segmentation. When I do this [d for d in data if d == "on" ] it returns more than one 'no' and it should not

Comment: thanks then I guess their file is corrupted, and I am not losing my mind.

Comment: Indeed - there are some really good duplicates in there, 5 x "o'clock" in 12 lines for instance.